# GetComponent return null InCollisionEnter2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

[image]

Im trying to shoot the robot and everytime the robot gets hit, the health bar decrease.
Somehow, in onCollisonEnter2D,
[image]
This function is in Bullet class.
I dont know why this code only works for the first time. With the second shoot, the enemy is null so it cannot get into the Fix function of Enemy Class.

Please help. Im learning.
Many thanks.

Im trying to shoot the robot and everytime the robot gets hit, the health bar decrease.
Somehow, in onCollisonEnter2D,
attachFull1340272
This function is in Bullet class.
I dont know why this code only works for the first time. With the second shoot, the enemy is null so it cannot get into the Fix function of Enemy Class.

Please help. Im learning.
Many thanks.

Comment: then its hitting something that does not have an enemycontroller.

Comment: Debug what it is hitting, that will show what it actually hit.  
`Debug.Log($"Hit {other.collider.name}");`